# How can I create folders based on last modified date in PHP?

Tags: php

Into my server I have a unique `upload` folder with thousands images, so I would like to re-organize them by using sub folders, something like `../uploads/img/year/month/filename`.

For all new images uploaded I'm using this piece of code that works for me:

```
$path = __DIR__ .'/../uploads/img/' . date("Y") . '/' . date("m") . '/' . $filename;

if (!is_dir($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0775, true);
}
```

How can I do the same for all my files already in upload folder, to make new directories and sort all the files by their last modified date?

**Eg.**

```
filename | last modified date
------   | ------
1.jpg    | 24/02/2016
2.jpg    | 24/04/2016  
3.jpg    | 24/06/2016  
4.jpg    | 20/08/2016  
5.jpg    | 24/08/2016
```

**Target:**

```
../uploads/img/2016/02/1.jpg
../uploads/img/2016/04/2.jpg
../uploads/img/2016/06/3.jpg
../uploads/img/2016/08/4.jpg
                      /5.jpg
```

**My try**

```
function grab_pictures() {
    $mpath = __DIR__ .'/../uploads/media';

    foreach (glob("$mpath/*") as $file) { 
        $lastmoddate = filemtime($file);
        $basename = basename($file);     
        $month = date("m", filemtime($lastmoddate));
        $year = date("Y", filemtime($lastmoddate));
        $newPath = __DIR__ .'/../uploads/media/' .$year. '/' .$month. '/';

        if (!is_dir($newPath)) {
            mkdir($newPath, 0775, true);
        }

        $newName = '/' .$year. '/' .$month. '/' .$basename;

        $this->db->query(sprintf("UPDATE `images` SET `path` = '%s', `time` = `time`", $newName));

        // Move the file into the uploaded folder
        move_uploaded_file($basename, $newPath);
    }

}
```

But it's not working, no files have been moved and only one folder was created (1970/01)

**SOLUTION**

```
function grab_pictures() {
    $mpath = __DIR__ .'/../uploads/media';

    foreach (glob("$mpath/*") as $file) {
      if(!is_dir($file)){ 
        $lastmoddate = filemtime($file);
        $basename = basename($file);     
        $month = date("m", $lastmoddate);
        $year = date("Y", $lastmoddate);
        $newPath = __DIR__ .'/../uploads/media/' .$year. '/' .$month. '/';

        if (!is_dir($newPath)) {
            mkdir($newPath, 0775, true);
        }

        $newName = '/' .$year. '/' .$month. '/' .$basename;

        $old_Path = $mpath. '/' .$basename;
        $new_Path = $mpath.$newName;

        $this->db->query(sprintf("UPDATE `tracks` SET `art` = '%s', `time` = `time` WHERE `art` = '%s'", $newName,$basename));

        // Move the file
        rename($old_Path, $new_Path);
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: `$path = __DIR__ .'/../uploads/img/' . date("Y") . '/' . date("m") . '/' . $filename;` *perhaps?*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, but it's not that simple. My problem is that I don't know how to do the same with files that are already into the server.

Comment: Not sure if you can do that...

Comment: @Tonza what about using  `filemtime()` ?

Comment: http://php.net/stat

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, any difference between `filemtime()` and `$stat['mtime'];` ?

Comment: @ilvalentino4ever: none. filemtime is pretty much literally just `function filemtime($file) { return stat($file)['mtime']; }` all of those file meta-info functions are stat() wrappers one way or another. stat() just gives you everything, filemtime gives you only the one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `filemtime(filename)` function available in PHP. It returns the timestamp which you can use with the date function 
Try `echo date("m d Y", filemtime(filename))`

Run the filemtime function in a for loop looping through all the files. This could be the flow of the loop.

1. Check the last modification date (filemtime(filename))
2. Store it in a variable (eg. mdate)
3. Check if a folder exists with the date (mdate)
4. If not, create a folder (use your $path variable)
5. Move the file to the new folder
6. Use this loop for all the files uploaded in the future too.

Check following code snippet here. It might just be what you're looking for.

```
foreach (glob("$parent_folder/*") as $file) { 
$lastmoddate = filemtime("$file");
... folder creation/checking and file moving stuff ...
}
```

I hope it helps clear something out. 
Check this [reference page for the usage of filemtime()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_filemtime.asp)

Comment: Why do you use `$parent_folder` and then `$folder` ?

Comment: @ilvalentino4ever in the "My Try" of yours, you are using `date("m", filemtime($lastmoddate))`

`$lastmoddate is the timestamp of the file modification date` . 

You don't need to run filemtime again on $lastmoddate .

Simply use `date("m", $lastmoddate)`

Let me know if it still throws errors :)

Comment: Thanks Ninad really helpful, I added my solution to the question ;)

Comment: @ilvalentino4ever Glad that you were able to get it solved :)