# How use filemtime to move all files by their last modified time

Tags: php, linux

Referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129279/how-can-i-create-folders-based-on-last-modified-date-in-php), I found difficulties using `filemtime();` to find out last modified time of files inside a folder.

I need to move all my files that are already inside `__DIR__ .'/../uploads/media';` to `__DIR__ .'/../uploads/media/YY/mm';` based on their last modified time.

Here my function:

```
function grab_pictures() {
    $mpath = __DIR__ .'/../uploads/media';

    foreach (glob("$mpath/*") as $file) { 
        //find timestamp of last modified time
        $lastmoddate = filemtime($file);
        //grab only the filename with extension for newPath
        $basename = basename($file);  
        //takes month from timestamp   
        $month = date("m", filemtime($lastmoddate));
        //takes Year from timestamp  
        $year = date("Y", filemtime($lastmoddate));
        //creates new folders /Year/month/ based on last modified time of each file
        $newPath = __DIR__ .'/../uploads/media/' .$year. '/' .$month. '/';

        if (!is_dir($newPath)) {
            mkdir($newPath, 0775, true);
        }

        $newName = '/' .$year. '/' .$month. '/' .$basename;

        //change path in MySQL
        $this->db->query(sprintf("UPDATE `images` SET `path` = '%s', `time` = 'time'", $newName));

        // Move files from old to the new path
        move_uploaded_file($basename, $newPath);
    }

}
```

What's wrong in my function? No files have been moved and only one folder was created (1970/01)

**SOLUTION**

Probably there are other better ways but here is my solution:

```
function grab_pictures() {
    $mpath = __DIR__ .'/../uploads/media';

    foreach (glob("$mpath/*") as $file) { 
        $lastmoddate = filemtime($file);
        $basename = basename($file);     
        $month = date("m", $lastmoddate);
        $year = date("Y", $lastmoddate);
        $newPath = __DIR__ .'/../uploads/media/' .$year. '/' .$month. '/';

        if (!is_dir($newPath)) {
            mkdir($newPath, 0775, true);
        }

        $newName = '/' .$year. '/' .$month. '/' .$basename;

        $old_Path = $mpath. '/' .$basename;
        $new_Path = $mpath.$newName;

        $this->db->query(sprintf("UPDATE `images` SET `path` = '%s', `time` = `time` WHERE `art` = '%s'", $newName,$basename));

        // Move the file
        rename($old_Path, $new_Path);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//takes month from timestamp   
$month = date("m", filemtime($lastmoddate));
//takes Year from timestamp  
$year = date("Y", filemtime($lastmoddate));
```

Why did you use `filemtime` on timestamp?
try this:

```
//takes month from timestamp   
$month = date("m", $lastmoddate);
//takes Year from timestamp  
$year = date("Y", $lastmoddate);
```

and you should use [rename](http://php.net/manual/it/function.rename.php) instead of `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: Thanks really usefull...I saw only one bad thing here, it makes subfolders of folders inside `$mpath` instead it should do this only for files, is there something I can do for it? (anyway I accept your answer)

Comment: try add at the begin of foreach
`if( is_dir( $file ))
continue;`

Comment: ok, so something like `foreach (glob("$mpath/*") as $file) { if( is_dir( $file )){ ...}}` Is it right?

Comment: I used `is_dir` because after `if` was `continue;`, which will stop current loop sequence and start it for next item in array. If you want use `if` for whole loop, use `is_file` instead of `is_dir`.

Comment: oh well I forgot the `!` before `is_dir` :)